# How to write Extracted Data in to A File In Gatling

Tags: performance-testing, scala-collections, gatling

I am using Gatling for load testing. When I am creating Customer profiles , Customer IDs will be generated. I am able to extract the customer ID and saving in to session variables.

But How to store these values in to a Text file.

please help me.

Answer (score 4):

There's several ways to achieve that.

If you're familiar with Scala, you can:

- open a file in your simulation
- write into it in a exec(function): https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Session#wiki-functions
- close the file (either register an ActorSystem shutdown hook, or use Gatling 2 snapshot after hook: https://github.com/excilys/gatling/issues/1475)

If this is too complex for you, the most simple way is to use logback:

- declare a logger in your simulation with a special name
- configure logback so this logger outputs in a dedicated FileAppender
- use a pattern that just logs the message

Regarding the second solution, check the logback documentation: http://logback.qos.ch/documentation.html

Comment: I had the same problem, and solution 1 made me nervous from a thread safety perspective. In the end, I went and implemented a custom "DumpData" action, which avoided these problems. It's a little overengineered to be a stack overflow answer, but I've been debating submitting it for inclusion into Gatling. Thoughts?

Comment: exec(function) is turned into a single actor, so it only deals with one message at a time and is perfectly threadsafe. And even if it wasn't the case, Java Writer is synchronized.

Answer (score 3):

In the example below I'm saving the extracted **NumberIDs** out of the SOAP response and then save them into the **numbersIDs.csv** file so that it can be fed into another Request.

```
//Variables to store the extracted values of the response
var numberIDs  : Seq[String] = _ 

//Java Writer    
val numberIDs_writer = {
   val fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream("numbersIDs.csv")
   new java.io.PrintWriter(fos,true)
}
val scn = scenario("basicSimulation")    
     .exec(http("Request_One")  
            .post("/services")
            .body(StringBody(inputXMLpayLoad))  
                        .headers(Request_One_Header)
                        .check(bodyString.saveAs("Request_Response")) //Save the response in a variable called Request_Response
                        .check((status.is(200)))
                    //Extract all numberIDs of the SOAP response
                        .check(regex("""<NumberId>([\d]+)</NumberId>""")
                            .findAll
                            .transform { string => numberIDs = string; string } 
                            .saveAs("numberIDs")))  
//Save variable numberIDs into the csv file
.foreach("${numberIDs}", "id") {
  exec(session => {
    numberIDs_writer.println(session("id").as[String])
    session
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since 2.0.0-M1, infoExtractor hook takes a Session parameter:
https://github.com/excilys/gatling/issues/1004

There's also a builtin that adds the Session content to simulation.log records when the request fails.
https://github.com/excilys/gatling/commit/b7b6299c658d0aa1b88971208eb0c98a9808e37f

You can adapt this example if you just want to log with logback.

```
class MySimulation extends Simulation with Logging {

def logSessionOnFailure(status: RequestStatus, session: Session, request: Request, response: ExtendedResponse): List[String] = {
    if (status == KO) logger.error(session)
    Nil
}

val httpConf = http
...
.extraInfoExtractor(logSessionOnFailure)

...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (not tested, but could work) is to use response transformer (call *.transformResponse* after *.post*). In the transformer body you would get a response object from which you can extract the generated ID and append it into a file, collection, etc.. Then just return the original response as the transformation result. This is however not a very nice solution from the design point of view, because your transformation has a side effect.